# How to Set a Custom Template for Blog Posts

Tags: page-template

I am trying to set a custom template for my blog posts page using the Template box on the Page Attributes section of the page.

However, the template does not get used on the site.

Is there a certain reason why or maybe a special process I need to go through to get a custom template to be used for the blog posts? Could it be the theme is overriding the custom page somehow?

Structurally the template is fine and appears as one of the template selections in the pulldown box.

Here are screen shots:

**This is from Settings**
[image]

**This is from the "Blog" Page Attributes:**

[image]

Comment: The `post` post type doesn't normally have the templates meta box that the `page` post type has. Can you verify this isn't something added by the particular theme you're using? See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) page to see how WordPress loads templates, note that posts don't have the custom template entry that pages have.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can't use Page Templates that way; you need to edit your index.php file instead.

[See this chart](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/wordpress-cheat-sheets-template-heirarchy-map--wp-22621) for more detail on how the hierarchy works and [this post](http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/) for a detailed explanation. By specifying "Blog" as the "posts page" on the Settings > Reading tab, you are telling WordPress "this is posts display area" which falls under the "[Home Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display)" hierarchy and no longer falls under the [Page Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display) hierarchy.

This allows you to have the page you've designated as the blog-page listed in menus and such, but it doesn't really act like a Page in any other ways. As I understand it. :)

Comment: [This is a bit more indepth](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)